# different catalog per user

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I want to add multiple catalogs from different Suppliers. Is it also possible in Magento to set a specific catalog per user. Next to that can a customer also choose their own catalog out of the multiple catalogs.

Comment: you can set price based on customer group

Comment: Yes but i want to know if for example I have camcorder from amazon and a earring from Six, that Customer A can only see the catalog from amazon and Customer B only from Six?

Comment: try this https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2